# How can I assign characters to variables using their ASCII reference numbers in shell?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, character, ascii

I am trying to write a shell script in which I want to assign certain characters to some variables. But since I want to cycle through a set of characters, I can't just write `char1='A'`. I want to be able to assign 'A' to the variable char1 using its ASCII cose number. I am also *very* new to shell scripting, so, if a detailed explanation of the command I need to use would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The following command will assign 65 (ASCII value of "A") to the variable char1:

```
char1=$(printf "%d" "'A")
```

The command printf is similar to the C function printf() which is used to print preformatted text. Using a quote(') before a character prints the ASCII equivalent of the character.

Comment: I guess my question was not very clearly stated. I want to do the opposite, i.e. use the number 65 as part of the command to assign 'A' to the variable, not the other way around.

Comment: Use `char1=$(printf "\x$(printf %x 65)")`